# Retornar de um sub menu para o menu principal de uma função em Python

Tags: python, sqlite3

Eu criei uma aplicação simples em Python referente a um sistema de agenda com o Sqlite3. São 3 arquivos o menu principal `agenda.py` o de `contato.py` e `usuario.py` que farão login no sistema.

No arquivo 'agenda.py' eu faço o login do usuário chamando a função login(conexao, login, senha) que está no arquivo 'usuario.py' que me retorna a função menuContatos() que está no arquivo 'contatos.py', dentro desse menu a opção 6 é sair retornando para o menu inicial de login do arquivo 'agenda.py' é ai que eu não consigo retornar para essa tela inicial

Abaixo está o código que estou utilizando.

**Agenda.py**

```
from usuario import *
from contatos import *
import getpass

print("\n\033[47m\033[31mConectando no banco...\033[0;0m\n")
conexao = sqlite3.connect("banco.sqlite")

print("\n--- Efetuar Login no Sistema ---\n")

usuario = input("Por favor, informe o usuário: ")

senha = getpass.getpass("Por favor, informe a senha: ")

login(conexao, usuario, senha)

print("\n\033[47m\033[31mFechando conexão com o banco...\033[0;0m\n")
conexao.close()
```

**contatos.py**

```
from usuario import *

# --- Função para criar a tabela ----
def criar_tabela_contato(conexao):

    cursor = conexao.cursor()

    sql = """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contato (
            nome text,
            fone text,
            email text,
            usuario integer
        );
    """

    cursor.execute(sql)

    conexao.commit()
# --------------------------------------------

#  --- Função para inserir o contato ---
def inserir_contato(conexao, nome, telefone, email, id):

    cursor = conexao.cursor()

    sql = """
        INSERT INTO contato VALUES(
            '{}',
            '{}',
            '{}',
             {}
        );
    """.format(nome, telefone, email, id)

    cursor.execute(sql)

    conexao.commit()
# --------------------------------------------

# --- Função para listar contatos ---
def listar_contato(conexao):

    cursor = conexao.cursor()

    sql = "SELECT rowid, * FROM contato ORDER BY nome;"

    cursor.execute(sql)

    contato = cursor.fetchall()

    print("\033[32mId Nome    Telefone     E-mail\033[0;0m\n")
    print("\033[32m== ======= ===========  ================\033[0;0m\n")
    for cont in contato:
        print("{}: {} - ({}) -".format(cont[0], cont[1], cont[2]), cont[3] )
# -----------------------------------------------------------

# --- Função para excluir contatos ---
def excluir_contato(conexao, id):

    cursor = conexao.cursor()

    sql = """
        DELETE FROM contato
        WHERE rowid = {};
    """.format(id)

    cursor.execute(sql)

    conexao.commit()
# ---------------------------------------------------------------

# --- Função para buscar contatos ---
def buscar_contato(conexao, nome):

    cursor = conexao.cursor()

    sql = "SELECT rowid, * FROM contato WHERE nome LIKE '%{}%';".format(nome)

    cursor.execute(sql)

    contato = cursor.fetchall()

    print("\033[32mId Nome    Telefone  E-mail\033[0;0m\n")
    print("\033[32m== ======= ========  ================\033[0;0m\n")
    for cont in contato:
        print( "{}: {} - ({}) -".format(cont[0], cont[1], cont[2]), cont[3] )
# ----------------------------------------------------------------

# --- Função para alterar contatos ---
def alterar_contato(conexao, nome, telefone, email, id):

    cursor = conexao.cursor()

    sql = "UPDATE contato SET nome = '{}', fone = '{}', email = '{}' WHERE rowid = {}".format(nome, telefone, email, id)

    cursor.execute(sql)

    conexao.commit()
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ========== Menu Principal ==========
def menuContatos():
    print("\n\033[47m\033[31mConectando no banco...\033[0;0m\n")
    conexao = sqlite3.connect("banco.sqlite")

    opcao = 0
    while opcao != 6:
        print("""\033[32m
Em relação aos contatos do sistema, você deseja...

        1 - Inserir
        2 - Buscar
        3 - Listar
        4 - Alterar
        5 - Excluir
        6 - Retornar
\033[0;0m""")

        opcao = int(input("\033[32mInforme a opção desejada: \033[0;0m"))

        if opcao == 1:
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Digite os dados do contato ---\033[0;0m\n")

            while True:
                n = input("Nome: ")
                if n == "":
                    print("\n\033[47m\033[30mEspaço vazio! Digite um nome...\033[0;0m")
                else:
                    break

            while True:
                t = input("Telefone: ")
                if t == "":
                    print("\n\033[47m\033[30mEspaço vazio! Digite um telefone...\033[0;0m")
                else:
                    break

            while True:
                e = input("E-mail: ")
                if e == "":
                    print("\n\033[47m\033[30mEspaço vazio! Digite um endereço de e-mail...\033[0;0m")
                else:
                    break

            while True:
                i = int(input("Id: "))
                if i == "":
                    print("\n\033[47m\033[30mEspaço vazio! Digite um Id...\033[0;0m")
                else:
                    break

            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Contato inserido com sucesso ---\033[0;0m\n")

            inserir_contato(conexao, n, t, e, i)

        elif opcao == 2:
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Buscar Registro ---\033[0;0m\n")

            nome = input("Digite o nome do contato: ")
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Registros Encontrados ---\033[0;0m\n")
            buscar_contato(conexao, nome)

        elif opcao == 3:
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Lista de contatos cadastrados ---\033[0;0m\n")
            listar_contato(conexao)

        elif opcao == 4:
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Alteraçao de Contatos ---\033[0;0m\n")

            n = input("Nome: ")
            t = input("Telefone: ")
            e = input("Email: ")
            i = int(input("Id: "))
            alterar_contato(conexao, n, t, e, i)
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Alteração realizada com sucesso ---\033[0;0m\n")

        elif opcao == 5:
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Exclusão de Registro ---\033[0;0m\n")

            id = input("Digite o ID para do contato para excluir: ")
            excluir_contato(conexao, id)
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Contato excluido com sucesso ---\033[0;0m")

        elif opcao == 6:
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Retornando para o Menu Agenda ----\033[0;0m\n")
            return login(conexao, usuario, senha)


    print("\n\033[47m\033[31mFechando conexão com o banco...\033[0;0m\n")
    conexao.close()
```

**usuarios.py**

```
import sqlite3
from contatos import *

# ---  Funções do Programa ---

# --- Função 1: Criação da Tabela ---
def criar_tabela_usuario(conexao):

    cursor = conexao.cursor()

    sql = """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario(
            nome text,
            login text,
            senha text
        );
    """

    cursor.execute(sql)
# ---------------------------------------------------

# --- Função 2: Inserir Usuário ---
def inserir_usuario(conexao, nome, login, senha):

    cursor = conexao.cursor()

    sql = """
        INSERT INTO usuario VALUES(
            '{}',
            '{}',
            '{}'
        );
    """.format(nome, login, senha)

    cursor.execute(sql)

    conexao.commit()
# ---------------------------------------------------

# --- Função 3: Listar Usuários ---
def listar_usuarios(conexao):

    cursor = conexao.cursor()

    sql = "SELECT rowid, * FROM usuario ORDER BY nome;"

    cursor.execute(sql)

    usuarios = cursor.fetchall()

    print("\033[34mId Nome    Login\n\033[0;0m")
    print("\033[34m== ======= =========\n\033[0;0m")
    for usr in usuarios:
        print( "{}: {} - ({})".format(usr[0], usr[1], usr[2]) )
# ---------------------------------------------------------------

# --- Função 4: Excluir Usuários ---
def excluir_usuario(conexao, id):

    cursor = conexao.cursor()

    sql = """
        DELETE FROM usuario
        WHERE rowid = {};
    """.format(id)

    cursor.execute(sql)

    conexao.commit()
# ---------------------------------------------------------------

# --- Função 5: Buscar Usuários ---
def buscar_usuario(conexao, nome ):

    cursor = conexao.cursor()

    sql = "SELECT rowid, * FROM usuario WHERE nome LIKE '%{}%';".format(nome)

    cursor.execute(sql)

    usuario = cursor.fetchall()

    print("\033[34mId Nome    Login\n\033[0;0m")
    print("\033[34m== ======= ========\n\033[0;0m")
    for usr in usuario:
        print( "{}: {} - ({})".format(usr[0], usr[1], usr[2]))
# -----------------------------------------------------------------

# --- Função 6: Alterar Contatos --
def alterar_usuario(conexao, nome, login, senha, id):

    cursor = conexao.cursor()

    sql = "UPDATE usuario SET nome = '{}', login = '{}', senha = '{}' WHERE rowid = {}".format(nome, login, senha, id)

    cursor.execute(sql)

    conexao.commit()

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#  --- Função 7: Login Menu Principal ---
def login(conexao, login, senha):

    cursor = conexao.cursor()

    sql = "SELECT rowid, * FROM usuario WHERE login LIKE '{}' AND senha LIKE '{}';".format(login, senha)

    cursor.execute(sql)

    usuario = cursor.fetchall()

    if usuario:
        for usr in usuario:
            print( "\n--- Bem Vindo! ---\n\n--- {} ---\n".format(usr[1]))
            return menuContatos()
    else:
        print("\n--- Usuário inválido! ---\n")
        print("...Retornado para o Menu Agenda...\n")

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# --- Menu Principal do Programa ---

def menuUsuario():
    print("\n\033[47m\033[31mConectando no banco...\033[0;0m\n")
    conexao = sqlite3.connect("banco.sqlite")

    opcao = 0
    while opcao != 6:
        print("""\033[34m
Em relação aos usuários do sistema, você deseja...

        1 - Inserir
        2 - Buscar
        3 - Listar
        4 - Alterar
        5 - Excluir
        6 - Voltar
\033[0;0m""")

        opcao = int(input("\033[34mOpção desejada: \033[0;0m"))

        if opcao == 1:
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m\--- Digite os dados do usuário ---\033[0;0m\n")

            while True:
                n = input("Nome: ")
                if n == "":
                    print("\n\033[47m\033[30mEspaço vazio! Digite um nome...\033[0;0m\n")
                else:
                    break

            while True:
                l = input("Login: ")
                if l == "":
                    print("\n\033[47m\033[30mEspaço vazio! Digite um login...\033[0;0m\n")
                else:
                    break

            while True:
                s = input("Senha: ")
                if s == "":
                    print("\n\033[47m\033[30mEspaço vazio! Digite um senha...\033[0;0m\n")
                else:
                    break

            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Contato inserido com sucesso ---\033[0;0m\n")

            inserir_usuario(conexao, n, l, s)

        elif opcao == 2:
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Buscar registro ---\033[0;0m\n")

            nome = input("Digite o nome do usuário para a busca: ")
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Registros Encontrados ---\033[0;0m\n")
            buscar_usuario(conexao, nome)

        elif opcao == 3:
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Lista de usuário cadastrados ---\033[0;0m\n")
            listar_usuarios(conexao)

        elif opcao == 4:
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Alteração de Usuários ---\033[0;0m\n")

            n = input("Nome: ")
            l = input("Login: ")
            s = input("Senha: ")
            i = input("Id: ")
            alterar_usuario(conexao, n, l, s, i)
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Alteração realizada com sucesso ---\033[0;0m\n")

        elif opcao == 5:
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Exclusão de registro ---\033[0;0m\n")

            id = input("Digite o ID para do contato para excluir: ")
            excluir_usuario(conexao, id)
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Usuário excluido com sucesso ---\033[0;0m\n")

        elif opcao == 6:
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Voltando ----\033[0;0m\n")
            break
    # Fechando a conexão (ligação) com o banco
    print("\n\033[47m\033[31mFechando conexão com o banco...\033[0;0m\n")
    conexao.close()
```

Comment: ainda está faltando colocar o erro, você falou na pergunta *"eu não consigo retornar para essa tela inicial"* mas não fala qual o problema, qual erro está apresentando ou o que está falhando.

Comment: Este é o erro que esta aparecendo: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sum_4\Downloads\Maycon - Atom\Algoritimos\agenda\agenda.py", line 16, in <module>
    login(conexao, usuario, senha)
  File "C:\Users\sum_4\Downloads\Maycon - Atom\Algoritimos\agenda\usuario.py", line 116, in login
    return menuContatos()
  File "C:\Users\sum_4\Downloads\Maycon - Atom\Algoritimos\agenda\contatos.py", line 187, in menuContatos
    return login(conexao, usuario, senha)
NameError: name 'login' is not defined

Comment: Deveria colocar na pergunta... e não em comentário. Editei minha resposta

Comment: Ok, obrigado! Agora está funcionando corretamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o seu menu principal não está dentro do while, e sim no escopo do módulo principal, assim, ele não se repete! depois que ele termina o programa acaba! Basta indentá-lo corretamente.

Marquei abaixo com um `_` os espaços que acrescentei, para você ver a área que faltou indentar:

```
from usuario import *
from contatos import *
import getpass

# Menu Principal Agenda ---
print("\n\033[47m\033[31mConectando no banco...\033[0;0m\n")
conexao = sqlite3.connect("banco.sqlite")

opcao = 0
while opcao != 2:
    print("""--- Menu Agenda ---

    1 - Entrar
    2 - Sair
    """)

____opcao = int(input("Escolha uma das opções: "))
____if opcao == 1:
____    print("\n--- Efetuar Login no Sistema ---\n")
____    usuario = input("Por favor, informe o usuário: ")
____    senha = getpass.getpass("Por favor, informe a senha: ")
____    login(conexao, usuario, senha)
____elif opcao == 2:
____    print("\nFechando o programa....\n")
____    break

print("\n\033[47m\033[31mFechando conexão com o banco...\033[0;0m\n")
conexao.close()
```

EDIT:

Além de fazer a alteração acima, você deve alterar a linha 187 de `contatos.py`, essa linha aqui:

```
return login(conexao, usuario, senha)
```

deve ficar somente assim:

```
return
```

Foi a função `login()`  que chamou a função `menuContatos()`... então para retornar para a função `login()` basta sair da função `menuContatos()` com `return`, sem chamar a função `login()` novamente.

Isso fará com que a função `login()` finalize também e então o fluxo de execução do código vai voltar para repetir o "Menu Agenda" através do `while` que coloquei na primeira parte da minha resposta, logo acima.

Comment: Sim, mais o problema está na opção 6 da função menuContatos que deveria retornar para o Menu Agenda da tela inicial do arquivo agenda.py com as opções 1 - Entrar e 2 - Sair. Quando eu executo a opção 6 esta dando erro de módulo.

Comment: @MayconWillianAlvesdaSilva qual o erro que está apresentando? Coloque o erro completo com traceback na pergunta

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta para melhor entendimento, acredito que fica mais fácil entender minha dúvida...